# Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context on a "standard" Linux system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mobile, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm writing a game engine using opengl 3.3/SDL/glew/Linux (Ubuntu 11.04). I want to keep the possibility to deploy on mobile (OpenGL ES 2). This means that I have to stay somewhat OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible.
Therefore my question is:
Is it possible to create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context using SDL/(existing patch on SDL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a GL ES 2.0 context on PC, you can use OpenGL 4.1, which has the `GL_ARB_es2_compatibility`, which adds the OpenGL ES functions that weren't in OpenGL, making them API compatible.

Comment: I think this one is pretty good except that it makes it easy to run opengl es programs on a opengl 4.1 context. But I want it tobe the other way around. I want to make sure that I'm not accidentally using features outside opengl es 2.0. I want tobe only using the intersecting set of features.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a nonofficial/patched version of SDL 1.2 you could simply use SDL 1.3.

Quoting myself on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606411/recommended-practice-environment-for-opengl-es-2-0):

> I suggest you download and setup the
>   [Khronos OpenGL ES 2.0 SDKs for
>   POWERVR SGX PC Emulation](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdk/KhronosOpenGLES2xSGX.asp) package
>   (Unfortunately you have to register to
>   be able to download). This allows you
>   to get everything up and running on a
>   desktop computer which will make your
>   life a lot easier when it comes to
>   debugging. You can then use C/C++ to
>   develop your OpenGL ES 2.0
>   applications.
>
> If I'm not mistaken my Android phone
>   (Samsung Galaxy S) also uses this
>   OpenGL implementation.
>
> Instead of using the Khronos SDK you
>   could also use the OpenGL ES 2.0
>   libraries from the Mesa3D Project
>   (Ubuntu has them in the repository).
>   They work fine but I can't recommend
>   them because I already ran into a
>   situation where the results differed
>   from the Khronos SDK implementation
>   and my Android device.
>
> **EDIT:** You also have to create a Window and an OpenGL rendering context
>   in order to actually use OpenGL. For
>   that I can recommend [SDL (1.3)](http://www.libsdl.org/hg.php)
>   which also has an official port for
>   Android. I tested it on Android and
>   Ubuntu with the mentioned SDK. It
>   allows me to use the same code for
>   both.

Comment: Creating the rendering context is not the issue. I already did that. I'm actually using SDL 1.3. I know that I can develop on an android phone. The whole point is that I want to develop opengl es 2.0 on my normal opengl 3.3 compatible machine/pc as opengl es 2.0 is a subset of it it shoud be technically possible. This could be realized by making SDL create a opengl es 2.0 compatible context.

Comment: Ah, right. I simply linked to the Khronos OpenGL ES 2.0 SDK libraries and SDL 1.3 seemed to be happy with that and was able to create the context and rendering to it worked and OpenGL ES was used.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the PowerVR SDK that requires a registration, you can use the ARM Mali equivalent that is an open download. Here it is: http://www.malideveloper.com/opengl-es-20-emulator.php. They can run on a Mesa software path if you don't have OpenGL 2.0 hardware underneath.