# Programming in Opengl-es 2.0 in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl-es-2.0

I have done coding in OpenGl now I want to switch to OpenGL-ES 2.0 I know we need an emulator to run OpenGL-es on linux . I have done some examples using PVRSDK but now i want to do  coding on my own . Can anyone tell me the way I can start coding in OpenGL-ES 2.0 for ubuntu 10.10.
Any tutorial or something like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [opengl es 2.0 on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809236/opengl-es-2-0-on-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the following threads as a starting point:

[Recommended practice environment for OpenGL ES 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606411/recommended-practice-environment-for-opengl-es-2-0/5606591#5606591) 
[Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context on a "standard" Linux system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976067/create-an-opengl-es-2-0-context-on-a-standard-linux-system/5976316#5976316)

I use SDL 1.3 with the PVRSDK. You could also use the Mesa OpenGL ES wrapper libraries from the software repositories.

And in OpenGL 4.1 there also is the `GL_ARB_es2_compatibility` extension which should allow you to use the OpenGL ES functionality without the extra libraries.

I prefer to test with the PVRSDK though since that is the one that my Android device uses.

Comment: ARB_es2_compatibility has nothing to do with OpenGL version 4.1. The extension may have been released around the same time as 4.1, but they are entirely orthogonal. Also, that extension only means that the API's *look* the same; it doesn't mean that they behave the same. They still use the desktop OpenGL behavior, not the OpenGL ES 2.0 behavior.